# Display Mathematics in swift

Tags: ios, swift, math

How do I display Mathematics in the iphone app that I am making in swift?

For example, I can use MathJax to display mathematics in wordpress, thus is there a program that I can import mathematics to use in swift or how else can I do that?

So far, mine is very simplistic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If all you're after is a higher baseline for the exponent and a lower baseline for the subscripts, use NSAttributedString and `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName`.

Or if you really like MathJax, you could use MathJax (and UIWebViews instead of UILabels).

Comment: I can confirm that MathJax and UIWebViews work fine with Swift.  I've used it for displaying optics equations in an iPad app.

Comment: I would need some guidance to set up MathJax locally with Swift, could anyone help, please?

Comment: Lots of tutorials on this, e.g. http://new2objectivec.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/tutorial-how-to-setup-mathjax-locally.html - if that still doesn't help, don't use comments here; ask a new question!

Comment: Here is a Swift port of the mathjax-ios example code from Google Code (originally Objective-C): https://github.com/thiloplanz/mathjax-ios  That should get you started in setting up MathJax locally with Swift.